# ERROR "nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, member-functions

```
#ifndef WORLD_H_
#define WORLD_H_
using namespace std;

class World{
public:
    friend class DoodleBug;
    friend class Ant;
    friend class Organism;
    int GRID_SIZE;
    
    World();   
    ~World();   
    
    void Draw();  
    int global_get_ID(int x, int y);  
    Organism* get_Ptr(int x, int y);  
    void set_Ptr(int x, int y, Organism* newOrg);  
    void TimeStepForward();  
    
protected:
    Organism* grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
};
#endif
```

In this .h file on line `Organism* grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE]` I get this error : Error : a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

What does it mean and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Size of array must be known at compile time, you can't use a (non-`constexpr`) class member for that.

Comment: A 2D array of _pointers_?  Has the world gone mad?  Anyway, check out [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as a solution to your immediate problem.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn’t see “return” in posted code?

Comment: @VladFeinstein sorry I didn't say it but this is a header .h file

Comment: Right, but in your question you said “ On line return Organism* grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] I get this error”. Where is “return”?

Comment: Will `get_Ptr` return nullptr when `x` or `y` are outside the world? Will you check the return value every time you call `get_Ptr`? The usual convention is to use `operator[]` without bounds checking or `at()` with bounds checking (throws) and to return a `Organism&`.

Comment: `set_Ptr` is mostly useless as you can just write `*world.get_Ptr(x, y) = newOrg;`. Or with the last comment `world.at(x, y) = newOrg;`.

Comment: `TimeStepForward()` is generally called `tick()`

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that in standard C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. But since `GRID_SIZE` is a non-static data member, the expression `GRID_SIZE` inside the class is actually equivalent to the expression `this->GRID_SIZE`. But the `this` pointer is more of a runtime construct and the expression `this->Grid_SIZE` is not a **constant expression** and cannot be used to specify the size of the array.

To **solve** this you can make the data member `GRID_SIZE` a `constexpr static` as shown below:

```
class World{
public:
//--vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------------->constexpr static added here
    constexpr static int GRID_SIZE = 10;
       
protected:
    Organism* grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
};
```

You can even use `static const`.

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ElFO3O_rv)

Comment: `static const`, `enum` or `enum class` works too. Anything that's constant across all instances of the class.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes i mentioned that also. Also i was just showing one way of doing it. And i prefer to use `constexpr` here in this example.

Comment: In that case you should prefer the even stronger `constinit` in C++20 because it actually forces the compiler to evaluate at compile time.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think the use of `consexpr` suffice here and there is no need to list all the possibilities. If the user understand one then he/she will be able to understand the others as well. That is, as long as the user understood why the error is generated(as explained in my answer), no need to add a list of all the available options.