# constexpr member functions gives C2131

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I've understood the differences between `const` and `constexpr` and their applications, but I can't get it's the following error:

```
// .hpp file
class MyClass {
public:
    constexpr double Square(double toBeSquared);
    static constexpr double Cube(double x);
    double ProcessRoutine();
};

// .cpp file
constexpr double alternative_square_routine(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}

double MyClass::Square(double toBeSquared)
{
    return x * x;
}

double MyClass::Cube(double x)
{
    return x * x * x;
}

double MyClass::ProcessRoutine()
{
    // C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
    constexpr double square_const = Square(10.0);
    // This is fine:
    const double another_square = Square(5.0);
    // This is also fine:
    constexpr double another_square_again = alternative_square_routine(5.0);
    // Even this is fine:
    constexpr double cube = Cube(3.0);
}
```

MSVC informs me that it's something involving the `this` pointer, while trying the code in Codiva.io (I guess it uses GCC) gives this output:

```
error: constexpr variable 'square_const' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: There are additional/other errors as well in your program. Always check the posted code before posting it in the question.

Comment: `this` is more of a runtime construct, and since `Square` is a non-static member function so `Square(10.0)` is actually `this->Square(10.0)` and so cannot be used in constexpr context.

Comment: See [ERROR "nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72241230/error-nonstatic-member-reference-must-be-relative-to-a-specific-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` just means that the variable, once initialized, should not be modifiable. The initialization will happen as normal for any other variable at runtime.

`constexpr` is much stronger and additionally enforces that the initialization is a *constant expression*, i.e. that it can be evaluated at compile-time when compiling the declaration, so that the compiler can replace the initialization with just the resulting value.

The rules for what expression qualifies as constant expression are very specific and can be found e.g. [here at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

Before [P2280](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html) `this` could only be evaluated in a constant expression evaluation if it is used inside a constexpr function being evaluated as part of the constant expression.

```
constexpr double square_const = Square(10.0);
```

is short for

```
constexpr double square_const = this->Square(10.0);
```

because `Square` is a non-static member function. And here you are evaluating `this` as part of the initialization of `square_const` which you want to be a constant expression (because of `constexpr`), while not in a `constexpr` function being evaluated as part of that constant expression evaluation.

P2280 has been accepted for C++23 and as defect report against C++11 to C++20. With it, using `this` here would be allowed as long as you don't try to access the value of `*this`. Since this is a recent defect report, compilers probably don't implement it yet. The cppreference link above isn't updated for it yet.

With just `const` instead of `constexpr` there is no requirement for any constant expression evaluation, so there is no reason for it to fail.

`alternative_square_routine` and `Cube` are fine, because there is no `this` involved. These are not non-static member functions.